# Parsing an echo in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, echo

I have what is, for me, quite a complex line I want to parse into php.

```
echo '<input class="cbox" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById('school').style.display ='inline'}else{document.getElementById('school').style.display ='none'}" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="School" checked/><br>';
```

Obviously, if I use speech marks to enclose the echo, it would fall apart in the onlick event.  How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To escape characters in php use the \ like so:

```
echo '<input class="cbox" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById(\'school\').style.display =\'inline\'}else{document.getElementById(\'school\').style.display =\'none\'}" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="School" checked/><br>';
```

Comment: Will tick once it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes with \"

Like this:

```
echo "<input class=\"cbox\" onclick=\"if(this.checked){document.getElementById('school').style.display ='inline'}else{document.getElementById('school').style.display ='none'}\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"type[]\" value=\"School\" checked/><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add slashes before `'`.

```
echo '<input class="cbox" onclick="if(this.checked){document.getElementById(\'school\').style.display =\'inline\'}else{document.getElementById(\'school\').style.display =\'none\'}" type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="School" checked/><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use double-quotes, you can escape any other double-quotes by putting the \ character before them.

There are some more details at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score -2):

NEVER use echo to output HTML.
But always type it as is

```
?>
<input class="cbox" 
 onclick="if(this.checked){
    document.getElementById('school').style.display='inline'
}else{
     document.getElementById('school').style.display ='none'}" 
type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="School" checked/><br>
```

Comment: Wont work, since I need it to change depending on $_POST data